# Group By with Min and Max Date using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to do some SQL on the data from the [SF Bay Area Bike Share](https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/sf-bay-area-bike-share) Kaggel Data

When I run this SQL:

```
/****** Select Bikes   ******/
SELECT count(t.[id]) as TripCount
,t.[bike_id]
FROM [dbo].[trip] t
Group By t.[bike_id]
having count(t.[id]) < 25
Order By TripCount asc
```

I get this result:

```
+-----------+---------+
| TripCount | bike_id |
+-----------+---------+
|         6 |     876 |
|        18 |     323 |
|        20 |     565 |
|        24 |     476 |
|        24 |     697 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Where what I really want is this:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
| TripCount | bike_id |  Min_date  |  Max_date  |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
|         6 |     876 | 2014-05-22 | 2014-05-27 |
|        18 |     323 | 2013-08-30 | 2013-09-07 |
|        20 |     565 | 2013-08-29 | 2013-09-07 |
|        24 |     476 | 2013-08-29 | 2013-09-07 |
|        24 |     697 | 2013-10-15 | 2013-12-20 |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

where the Min Date & Max Date give respectively the first & last date the bike made a trip.

I can do this manually for each bike by running this:

```
SELECT 
min(cast([start_date] as date)) as Min_Date
,max(cast([start_date] as date)) as Max_Date
,[bike_id]
FROM [dbo].[trip]
where bike_id = '697'
Group By bike_id
```

I tried this query:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT 
count (t.[id]) as TripCount
,min(cast(t.[start_date] as date)) as Min_Date
,max(cast(t.[start_date] as date)) as Max_Date
,[bike_id]
FROM [dbo].[trip] t
Group By count (t.[id]), bike_id
```

and obviously got the following error:
*Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.*

Just not quite sure how to wrap my head around this...

Comment: Thx for fixing my tables!  SE really should add in the ability to use table in at least this community!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close

```
SELECT
[bike_id] 
,count (t.[id]) as TripCount
,min(cast(t.[start_date] as date)) as Min_Date
,max(cast(t.[start_date] as date)) as Max_Date
FROM [dbo].[trip] t
Group By  bike_id
```

Comment: Thank You - so the order of my select was breaking it for me?  The error message COULD maybe have given me a better clue I think...

Comment: @kiltannen Columns in the select without aggregate functions(SUM,MAX,etc) need to be added in the GROUP BY. You added a aggregate function in the GROUP BY, order of the select doenst matter